# VS2010 Silverlight 4 loading wrong project module

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, silverlight-4.0

I have a sliverlight web application in VS2010.  I have several projects in the solution,
one of them I use as a library of dialog boxes and other screens used in the other projects.

I edited one such dialog box, a child window, and added an extra row to the layout grid and
a combobox to the row.  I rebuilt the soluition and my change appears in one sub-project but
not in another.

For the purpose of discussion here are the module names:

Manage - uses the child window 'add' in SilverlightClassLibrary2

Policy - uses the child window 'add' in SilverlightClassLibrary2

SilverlightClassLibrary2 - contains the child window 'add'

Note that this has been working for years until now.

My first indication of a problem was I could not hit a break point in Manage, it would
say no symbols loaded.  I checked the references to SilverlightClassLibrary2 and they point
to the correct dll in the debug folder.  A full recompile changes the date-time stamp of
the SilverlightClassLibrary2.dll everywhere.  I deleted all dll's manually and re-compiled
and still manage has the old version of 'add' and policy has the new changes.

I'm at a loss as to where manage is getting an old copy of SilverlightClassLibrary2.dll
It is obviously looking somewhere else, this would also explain why the symbols are not
being loaded. It's not looking in the release folder, even so I re-compiled in release mode
to make sure it too had the changes. I deleted and re-added the reference (a project reference) to the SilverlightclassLibrary2.dll, still the same problem.

So where can I look to figure out what is going on with this?

SOLVED:

ahhhhhhh...it was chrome's browser cache that was giving me the old code.

As for the breakpoint issue, solved by using IE8 (i'm on xp) instead of chrome.

Comment: Instead of saying "**SOLVED**", you should answer and accept your own question so that others can quickly see the question has been answered.

Comment: Agreed, but with less than 10 rep pts I could not answer my own question until after 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

ahhhhhh...it was chrome's browser cache.  I cleared it and now I see my changes.

Still can't hit the break point in chrome (no symbols loaded for some modules) even after clearing chrome's cache, but the breakpoints do work in IE8.

There was a suggestion to look at debug -> windows -> modules and locate the errant module and manually load symbols - but the module I want is not listed even though I navigate my app to the page in question.  I use a line like this:

dim cw as new SilverlightClassLibrary2.Add

to create the child window, so perhaps this does not show up in the module list when using chrome?  In IE8 the SilverlightClassLibrary2 module does show up in the list.  strange.